# Decomposition of a positive semidefinite self-adjoint operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

If I have a positive semi-definite self-adjoint operator $H:D(H) \rightarrow L^2$, is it true that there is always a decomposition $H=A^* A$ available? If this is true, what can we say about the domains of $A$ and $A^*$?

Comment: The decomposition is certainly not unique; if $A^*A = H$, then $(UA)^*(UA) = H$ as long as $U^*U = \mathsf{id}$

Comment: you are right, this is not even unique in the finite-dim. case, I will delete it, thanks.

Comment: Here's a reference: http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ8_01%2FS1446788700004560a.pdf&code=6cd7c32f33d2b272d563057d88374391

Comment: sorry, where exactly is this theorem? I honestly went through this 3 times, but I must have always missed it...

Comment: @user159356: (I just happened to check back.  You can notify others: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.)  Positive self-adjoint square roots exist for positive self-adjoint operators. Take $A=\sqrt{H}$. Although I have only read the introduction to the linked paper, it appears to contain an elementary proof of the existence of square roots of positive self-adjoint operators, and then uses this to prove the spectral theorem.  The reverse implication is the more common way to think about it, but this way has less start up cost for demonstrating what you want.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use unbounded operators, then
$$
               H = \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda dE(\lambda).
$$
The spectrum theorem for unbounded selfadjoint operators has the excellent provision that
$$
  \mathcal{D}(H) = \left\{ x \in X : \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{2}d\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} < \infty\right\}.
$$
You have $H=A^{2}$, where $Ax=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{\lambda}dE(\lambda)x$ defines a positive selfadjoint operator with
$$
      \mathcal{D}(A) = \left\{ x \in X : \int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda\|E(\lambda)x\|^{2} < \infty\right\}.
$$
You're guaranteed that $A\mathcal{D}(H)\subseteq\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $A^{2}=H$.

For example, if $H=-\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}$ on the space of twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ with $f,f'' \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, then the operator can be written in terms of the Fourier transform:
$$
                 A=\left(|s|f^{\wedge}(s)\right)^{\vee}.
$$
Here $\mathcal{D}(A)=\{ f : f, sf^{\wedge}(s)\in L^{2}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $H:X \to X$ is a bounded operator, there is indeed always such a decomposition available.  We may construct one such decomposition as follows:

By the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators), we have
$H = UTU^*$
Where the operator $T$ is given by
$$
[T(\phi)](x) = f(x)\phi(x)
$$
For some $f:\Bbb R \to \sigma(H) \subset [0,\infty)$.  We can simply define $\sqrt T$ by 
$$
[\sqrt T(\phi)](x) = \sqrt{f(x)}\phi(x)
$$
and from there, we can set $A = \sqrt{T} U^*$ and find $H = A^*A$.

In general, $A:X \to Y$ and $A^*:Y \to X$, where $Y$ is some space with dimension greater than or equal to the rank of $H$.

Comment: the question is about unbounded operators....

Comment: I am not sure about the case of an unbounded operator.  I would hope that some similar construction can always be applied.  I'll think about it.

Comment: Terry Tao's blog post here seems to address exactly this issue (spectral theorem and functional calculus for unbounded operators), and seems to suggest your argument would still work in the unbounded case, http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/
I'm not an expert on this and didn't fully read the post though, so take it with a grain of salt.